# Exception after Locating a Detail TAdoQuery

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado, master-detail

I have a master and a detail `TAdoQuery` called `FMaster` and `FDetail`. They are connected via the DataSource `FMasterSource`. The detail query has a parameter, which is automatically filled and updated depending on the master query.

Now the problem is: After doing a `FDetail.Locate` (or in fact `FDetail.Recordset.Clone`), `FMaster.Next` throws an exception while trying to requery `FDetail` with the new parameter:

```delphi
  try
    FMaster.Open;
    FDetail.Open;
    FDetail.Locate('Id', 2, []);
    FMaster.Next; {<== throws Exception with ADO Errorcode 0x80040e05}
  finally
    FDetail.Close;
    FMaster.Close;
  end;
```

According to [this List](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6420_tc3_database_server/108091659.html&id=), Errorcode `0x80040e05` means "Object already open".

- The problem seems to be, that `FDetail.Locate` creates a clone of the underlying Ado Recordset for later use, and saves it. We can therefore replace the Locate by
  `recordsetClone := FDetail.Recordset.Clone(adLockReadOnly);` (which `uses Winapi.ADOInt`) and get the same error.
- Inside `FMaster.Next`, the exception gets thrown by trying to requery `FDetail` after the new parameter for MasterId is set. This happens in `TCustomADODataSet.RefreshParams`.
- When you disconnect Detail from Master, everything works just fine. Setting the parameter of `FDetail` by hand works just fine.

What did I miss?
Is it an error in the VCL?
Or is it yet another weird ADO bug?

### Source Code

I am using Oracle 11g XE and Delphi 10.4 Sydney.

Oracle tables:

```sql
drop table Detail;
drop table Master;

create table Master (
  Id NUMBER(2) not null, 
  constraint MasterPK primary key (Id)
);
create table Detail (
  Id       NUMBER(2) not null, 
  MasterId NUMBER(2), 
  constraint DetailPK primary key (Id),
  constraint DetailFK foreign key (MasterId) references Master(Id)
);
insert into Master values (1);
insert into Master values (2);
insert into Detail values (1,1);
insert into Detail values (2,1);
insert into Detail values (3,2);
```

Delphi code:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Initializing...
  FConnection.Provider := 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1';
  FConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TEST;Data Source=XE';
  FConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
  FConnection.KeepConnection := False;

  FMaster.Connection := FConnection;
  FMaster.SQL.Text := 'select Id from Master';
  FMaster.CursorLocation := clUseServer;
  FMaster.CursorType := ctStatic;

  FMasterSource.DataSet := FMaster;

  FDetail.Connection := FConnection;
  FDetail.DataSource := FMasterSource;
  FDetail.SQL.Add('select Id, MasterId from Detail where MasterId = :Id');
  FDetail.Parameters[0].DataType := ftInteger;
  FDetail.CursorLocation := clUseServer;

  //Do stuff
  try
    FMaster.Open;
    FDetail.Open;
    //FDetail.Locate('Id', 2, []);
    recordsetClone := FDetail.Recordset.Clone(adLockReadOnly);
    FMaster.Next; {<== throws Exception with ADO Errorcode 0x80040e05}
  finally
    FDetail.Close;
    FMaster.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not sure, since normally I'd implement this myself without setting the master dataset, but I think you shouldn't open the detail dataset yourself. The detail dataset should be (re)opened by opening or scrolling through the master dataset. Locating the right record can then probably be done in the AfterOpen event of the detail dataset.

Comment: Not an answer, but the way you use try/finally to protect Open with Close is wrong. You need TWO try/finally. FDetail.Open may fail and leave FMaster opened.

Comment: @fpiette I tried to avoid two try/finally blocks for readability. Question is fixed. If Close is called for a DataSet which is not active, nothing happens, so it should work this way.

Comment: @GolezTrol I just tried it: Opening `FMaster` does not automatically open `FDetail`. Non-`Active` detail datasets seem to be ignored everywhere. I'm not sure if the error message "Object already open" really means much: I have an ADO book stating that this message also occurs when ADO tries to establish a second connection automatically, which might not be supported by Oracle. (Aparrently ADO does this for things that are not possible with only one connection).

Comment: Maybe ADO closes `FDetail` and tries to open the clone for some reason. I had another situation where it seemed like ADO confused two recordsets querying the same table. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this behavior atm.